# Using the Lists web service in SharePoint 2007, how can I update the Author value programatically?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2007

I have a process that uploads a file to a SharePoint form list and would like the Author (Created By) column to be the user who created the file and not the process user. I have been trying the UpdateListItems method of the Lists web service and can update other fields but not the Author field.

Here is a sample of the CAML text I have been trying.

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
        <Field Name="ID">3396</Field>
        <Field Name="Author"><USERID>;#<USERNAME></Field>
    <Field Name="Created_x0020_By"><DOMAIN>\<USERLOGIN></Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

Any help or ieda would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can update Author field after you clear ReadOnly attribute with UpdateList() method. After it you can set Author field by UpdateListItems() method.